# DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive in vagrant in windows

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm using virtualbox-4.3 and vagrant-1.8.4 on windows machine. At the time of starting vagrant getting below error continue :

```
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive
```

Here I can't disable the key (`config.ssh.insert_key = false`) because using vagrant I've insert the key in ubuntu guest machine.

this configuration working in Linux machine !

Have a idea about ?